# How to get project infos from Eclipse "Open Call Hierarchy"?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get a call-chain report of some methods in eclipse,
so I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the method call hierarchy view, 
and press numpad_multiply key to expand all nodes.

The problem is that I need to click each node to know which project it belongs to.

Is there any way or plugin to get a report?

(I use Eclipse 3.5 Galileo Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Thanks for any advices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my question, I hope this helps someone. 
(It’s not a clever way, but it works for me.)

Prepare:

1. Ctrl+Alt+H to open the method call hierarchy view, and press numpad_multiply key to expand all nodes.
2. Ctrl+A to select all nodes.
3. Copy fully qualified class name, and save it to a file somewhere (eg. c:\tmp.txt)
4. Remove all method name in above file.

   example:

   ```
     com.test.Class1.method1(Long, String)-> com.test.Class1
   ```

Source:

1. Create a new project (type java) in same workspace
2. Add target project reference to new project
3. Loop each line of above file (eg. c:\tmp.txt), end use this code to get the class location:

   ```
           /**
            * Get class file location
            * @param path : example: com.test.Class1
            * @return : example: /D:/workspace/project/target/com/test/Class1.class
            * @throws ClassNotFoundException
            */
           private static String getFileLocationByClassName(String path) 
               throws ClassNotFoundException {
               if (path == null || path.length() == 0)
                   return "";
               Class<?> forName = Class.forName(path);
               URL resource = forName.getResource(forName.getSimpleName() + ".class");
               if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(resource.getProtocol()))
                   throw new IllegalStateException("Class is not stored in a file.");
               return resource.getPath();
           }
   ```
4. Note that [project/target] in return is the project name, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

On Kepler, there is a down arrow (called "View Menu") in the right of the window, where you can check "Show File Names"